# Printing the text on Opengl

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Which is the easiest way to print the text in Opengl? I use this method but it cannot be used twice in my code.

```
unsigned char string[] = "Quadrant II";
    glRasterPos2f (-215, 215);
    glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
    int len = strlen(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, string[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why can't it be used twice?

Comment: I don't know too but It's show only one.

Comment: @Pheakdey: You may get more helpful answers if you post  the code of you "using it twice" that doesn't work.